# Dirichlet kernel identity $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}=1+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kx)$

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

My question is about Dirichlet kernel identity. Why is the following true?

$$\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}=1+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kx)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $e^{ikx}+e^{i(-k)x}=2cos(kx)$, for all $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: Can I just check, if you have the representation $2\sum^{n}_{k=0}\cos(kx)$ then if you evaluate the first term ($k=0$) would that not give the an extra $2$ rather than $1$ in the identity?

Comment: @GeorgeSimpson, Yes we have an extra 2 in that case.

Comment: Sorry to be really stupid, but with that in mind, how come there is a $+1$ in the trigonometric Dirichlet representation rather than a $+2$?

Comment: @GeorgeSimpson, If $k=0$ then $k=-k$ and there is one $+1$ not two.