# Closed form of the Dirichlet kernel: $\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N} e^{inx} =\frac{\sin((N+1/2)x}{\sin(x/2)}$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I got some tedious computation on the way of showing the closed expression for the Dirichlet kernel. I do not understand one step. Perhaps one can help me? Is this somewhat Euler formula?

$$\sum_{n=-N}^{N} e^{inx} = ... = \frac{1-\exp(i(N+1)x}{1-\exp(ix)} + \frac{1-\exp(-iNx)}{1-\exp(-ix)}= \frac{\sin((N+1/2)x}{\sin(x/2)}$$

**Question**: how can I get the last equality?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how this last step follows...

Comment: OK: Try to muliply the first part by $e^{-ix/2}/e^{-ix/2}$ and the second part by $e^{ix/2}/e^{ix/2}$

Comment: Write instead that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-N}^N e^{inx} = e^{-i N x} \sum_{n=0}^{2N} e^{inx} = e^{-i N x}  \frac{1-e^{i (2N+1) x} }{1-e^{ix}}$ and multiply the denominator and numerator by $e^{-ix/2}$

Answer (score 3):

First (see [Dirichlet kernel identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/700061/622884)) prove that $$\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N} e^{inx} = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \cos (nx) .$$

Denote $D_N(x)=1 + 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \cos (nx)$, and multiply it by $\sin (\frac{x}{2})$ :

$$\sin (\frac{x}{2})D_N(x) = \sin (\frac{x}{2}) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} 2\sin (\frac{x}{2})\cos (nx) ,$$

Use here the trigonometric product identity

> $2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(\alpha - \beta) $

and the oddity of $\sin$ to get
$$\sin (\frac{x}{2})D_N(x) = \sin (\frac{x}{2}) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \bigg( \sin\big( (n+\frac{1}{2})x \big) - \sin\big( (n-\frac{1}{2})x \big) \bigg).$$
**Hint:** you can reorganize the right hand side of this last equation, so that a [telescopic sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) is obtained: all terms except of
$$\sin\big( (N+\frac{1}{2})x \big) $$cancel , therefore
$$D_N(x) = \frac{\sin\big( (N+\frac{1}{2})x \big)}{\sin (\frac{x}{2})}.$$
You could also see another proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel#Proof_of_the_trigonometric_identity).